# undefined variable name while checking if-else conditions in go

Tags: go

I have written the following program while learning from a tutorial. This is about checking conditionals in `go`.
However, it is throwing error as `undefined message`. Please help.

```golang
// Check out various conditional operators

package main

import "fmt"

func condition(x int) string {
    if x > 5 {
        message := "x is greater than 5"
    } else if x == 5 {
        message := "x is equal to 5"
    } else {
        message := "x is less than 5"
    }
    return message  // error on this line
}

func main() {
    x := 10 - 5
    msg := condition(x)
    fmt.Println("%s", msg)
}
```

Output receiving is:

```
user$ go run conditionals.go 
# command-line-arguments
./conditionals.go:15:9: undefined: message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message` is scoped in each of the if/else branches. You want it scoped at the function level:

```
func condition(x int) string {
    var message string
    if x > 5 {
        message = "x is greater than 5"
    } else if x == 5 {
        message = "x is equal to 5"
    } else {
        message = "x is less than 5"
    }
    return message
}
```

Since you are returning this value, you can update the function signature to include the returned variable e.g.

```
func condition(x int) (m string) {

    if x > 5 {
        m = "x is greater than 5"
    }
    // ...

    return // implicitly returns m value
}
```

Comment: In your second code-block, the assignment needs to be: `m = "x is greater than 5"` and not `message = "x is greater than 5"`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you define `message` within a scope (i.e., inside curly braces), and your return statement is outside of those brackets. A solution would be to define `message` in the same scope as your return statement, and then redefine `message` in each conditional clause.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func condition(x int) string {
    message := ""
    if x > 5 {
        message = "x is greater than 5"
    } else if x == 5 {
        message = "x is equal to 5"
    } else {
        message = "x is less than 5"
    }
    return message
}

func main() {
    x := 10 - 5
    msg := condition(x)
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/z_8h0ISNKYO